# How to describe a place/society where criminal/offenders lives in a single word except prison/jail?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Would be great if someone here suggest a single or at max two words for where offenders/criminals live. I was thinking of something like "Infringed Element Society" but its a quite long phrase.I am not considering "Prison" since you may find under trial persons as well along with criminals/offenders.

Also I'd like to know what word or phrase is used to describe where "law abiding citizens" live.

Comment: They are often said to live on the *margins* of society.

Comment: Is the word "jail" correct? A jail where offenders/criminals lives?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for.  Do you mean a physical place where they live, like a house or a neighborhood, or do you mean the kind of society they live in?

Comment: @stangdon, would like to know society but if it would be house that also works. Except "prison" where one not sure if all are offenders/criminals because in prison you may find a person under trial.

Comment: If you're looking for synonyms of "prison" then use a thesaurus. I find the rest of your question rather unclear. There is no specific place where non-criminals live because it's the default situation and, by default, people can live wherever they want, within reason.

Comment: There are a number of examples where a country has sent criminals to live in a remote society rather than incarcerating them in a prison.  Those are typically referred to as prison colonies.  As far as law abiding citizens, they generally live where they want; there's no special term.

Answer (score 2):

I would call such a place a [*penitentiary*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/penitentiary).

> 1) (in the US and Canada) a state or federal prison: in Canada, esp a federal prison for offenders convicted of serious crimes
>
> 5b) (US)
>   a state or federal prison for persons convicted of serious crimes

A jail includes people arrested or on trial. The usage of prison is more mixed, but in general I think a prison would only include convicted persons. To better answer this might require law enforcement experience.

You can use [*incarcerate*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/incarcerate) to describe the state of such persons.